# do custom functionality after login in magento 2

Tags: php, magento, magento2.2

I was trying to execute a custom functionality, after successful login of customer in `magento 2.2` site.

I tried to execute some of my code in **/`<Magento-installed-directory>`/vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Ajax/Login.php** and also in **/`<Magento-installed-directory>`/vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/LoginPost.php**.

And none of the code is being executed, even `error_log("Login Success...")` is not logging any error.

Please do suggest some ideas regarding this.

Comment: You need to understand how to [Override a layout in magento 2](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html) and for magento question there is a section just for magento [stackover flow for magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/213753/magento-2-override-core-interface-and-model)

Comment: great i will look into it, but [magento doc](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html) this doesn't helped like you suggested

Comment: great, the other link you shared helped me a lot